# Remove the TouchEvent of Button

Tags: android, button, touch

I want to remove the `TouchEvent` of Button when the User moves out of the `Button` Area

I have detected the user movement by:

```
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

            rect = new Rect(v.getLeft(), v.getTop(), v.getRight(), v.getBottom());

            break;

   case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

            if(!rect.contains(v.getLeft() + (int) event.getX(), v.getTop() + (int) event.getY())){
                        logIt("You are OutSide...");
                    }

                    break;
```

Can Anyone Suggest how to do that...
    ANy answer Appreciated...Thks

Answer (score 0):

reWrite code like this :-

case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

```
        rect = new Rect(v.getLeft(), v.getTop(), v.getRight(), v.getBottom());

        break;
```

case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

```
        if(!rect.contains(v.getLeft() + (int) event.getX(), v.getTop() + (int) event.getY())){
                    logIt("You are OutSide...");
                }

                break;
```

Comment: I want to remove the onTouchEvent of my Button....when my user moves out of the Button Area...:)

Comment: i think When you set ACTION_UP then your touch event will remove

Comment: " remove the touch event " means you want to disable event?

Comment: I am moving to other view which contain a scrolling  action...IF disabling can stop the touch then yes

Comment: i didn't get you ..can you explain briefly ?

Comment: I just want that when I move my finger from my Button Area & go to other View , the TouchListener of Button should not get called and the Touch of the OtherView should getCall

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        rect = new Rect(v.getLeft(), v.getTop(), v.getRight(),v.getBottom());
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        if (!rect.contains(v.getLeft() + (int) event.getX(), v.getTop()+ (int) event.getY())) {
            Log.i(TAG, "You are outside");
            return false;
        }
        break;
```

and this complete code will give you some idea...

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        rect = new Rect(v.getLeft(), v.getTop(), v.getRight(),v.getBottom());
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        if (!rect.contains(v.getLeft() + (int) event.getX(), v.getTop()+ (int) event.getY())) {
            Log.i(TAG, "You are outside");
            return false;
        }
        break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I have used the onTouch of Actitvity...but it is not catching any event...as deathember mentioned

Answer (score 0):

Simpliest way :

```
onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){

...

case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
    event.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_UP);
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
...
}
```

In That case you will reject all next events related on your button.

Comment: @nitesh how it is undefined? onTouchEvent() is available in Activity and View. where you are writing this code?

Comment: @deathember...whant this in Actitvity  onTouchEvent() event or BUtton setOnTouchListener()

Comment: @deathember Thks but this didn't call the ACTION_UP atall